# Write a program with the same function as the min method in python

Tags: python

I don't have any ideas of my head, just know min(); in python to complete the function

```
for (i in seq_along(x[  i  ])){

if (x[  i  ] < x[  i+1  ]) {print(x[  i  ])}

}
```

Comment: Please take a look at [ask] a proper question

Comment: Are you asking how to implement `min` from scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea, just need to fix the syntax. You basically loop over all the items, and have a local variable that keeps track of the lowest value. Also you can handle getting an empty sequence, in which case the behavior of built-in `min` is to raise a `ValueError`.

```
def my_min(data):
    if len(data) < 1:
        raise ValueError('my_min() arg is an empty sequence')
    lowest = data[0]
    for value in data:
        if value < lowest:
            lowest = value
    return lowest
```

Examples

```
>>> my_min([10, 5, 20, 7])
5

>>> my_min([])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#14>", line 1, in <module>
    my_min([])
  File "<pyshell#12>", line 3, in my_min
    raise ValueError('my_min() arg is an empty sequence')
ValueError: my_min() arg is an empty sequence
```

Depending on your requirement, technically `min` takes a `key` argument which is a custom function to use for `<` comparison. You could extend your `my_min` function to add this too if required.